# Installation error while installing from CD-ROM

Tags: installation, live-cd

I am trying to install ubuntu 12.04. And i have windows 7 already installed.
But while installing through CD-ROM i'm getting this error:

```
Unable to find medium for connecting live file system
```

Comment: Check the CD, Drive, or controller.

Answer (score 0):

Is you CD-ROM connected trough a USB by any chance?
If it is make sure it is not connected to a USB 3